# tilde expansion in environment variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tilde-expansion

In my .sh file, I have this, `cp $file $SOME_PATH`, while `$SOME_PATH` is exported as `export SOME_PATH="~/path/to/path/"`. But when I ran this .sh file, I got error message saying like *no such "~/path/to/path/" exists.*
I replaced `~` as `$HOME`, then the error was gone.
So what's up here with the tilde?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use

```
SOME_PATH=~/path/to/path/
```

if you path have spaces, quote it

```
SOME_PATH=~/"path with spaces"
```

Comment: "path with space" -> path\ with\ space

Answer (score 2):

Remove the quotation marks on your export:

```
export SOME_PATH=~/path/to/path/
```

Comment: Thanks, but this seems not available, either.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Actually, I used cp $file "$SOME_PATH". ^_^

Comment: Does it work with all quotation marks removed? You basically have to prevent literal interpretation.